# Linux determine ZIP size without compression

Tags: linux, zip, compression, gzip, archive

I would like to make a ZIP file using `zip` command. Zip file would contain large number of directories containing large numbers of subdirectories, files etc.

Is there any way to calculate final size of ZIP file, but before doing actual zipping on the disk?

For example: Calculating final ZIP file size to determine if ZIP will fit into specific size container (we cannot perform on disk operation even in tmp, because if it will not fit, then zipping will fail without giving info on archive size)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [zip man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip):

> Streaming input and output. zip will also accept a single dash ("-") as the zip file name, in which case it will write the zip file to standard output, allowing the output to be piped to another program.

So:

```
$ zip -r - foo | wc -c
```

Will tell you the compressed size in bytes of the directory foo.

7z can not write to stdout for zip files.

The other alternative is to create a memory disk and compress to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can compress to StdOut and count the bytes, but AFAIK `zip` doesn't zip to stdout (and neither does `7z`, the other utility that can produce a ZIP format)(*).

On Linux you typically produce .tar.gz files and the utilities output to stdout if no output file is specified:

```
# compute size
outputSize=$(tar -cz the_directories | wc -c)
# create file
tar -czf some.tar.gz the_directories
```

Note that in any case you do the compression twice, you cannot really predict the output size without performing the conversion.

(*) possibly due to the fact that you cannot decode a ZIP file without seeing the end first.

Comment: D’oh! Writing to stdout (if you can) is simpler than messing with a pipe / process substitution.

Comment: zip is able to compress to stdout.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
tar  cf  >(wc -c)  <file_name_arguments>;  sleep 1
```

Rather than writing to a file,
`tar` will write to a pipe to a `wc -c` command,
which will report the number of bytes written to it. 
(Include any `tar` options you need to get it to do compression.) 
This uses bash’s “process substitution” functionality. 
Use the `sleep 1` because, without it,
your shell will issue its next shell prompt
when the `tar` command finishes,
and will not wait for the `wc` command to finish.

If you don’t have bash,
you can probably accomplish the same thing with a named pipe.